# ¿Cómo podría iterar de esta forma? iteracion de 3 en 3 para obtener este resultado

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quiero que mi carrousel quede de esta forma:

[image: addad]

lo estoy trayendo de la base de datos de esta forma y mi componente viene así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo podría solucionarlo no encuentro forma

```
 <div style={{ paddingLeft: "5%", marginTop: "5%", paddingRight: "10%" }}>
      <div id="women">
        <Carousel autoplay>
          {product.map((item) => (
            <div>
              <Row justify="space-around" key={item._id}>
                <Col span={7}>
                  <img src={item.productImage} alt="womenswear" height={300} />
                </Col>
                <Col span={7}>
                  <img src={item.productImage} alt="womenswear" height={300} />
                </Col>
                <Col span={7}>
                  <img src={item.productImage} alt="womenswear" height={300} />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la estructura del objeto **item** y/o **product**?  Si te fijas estas usando en cada ciclo del map el mismo **src=** con el valor `{item.productImage}` y de ahi que se repita.  Si no sabemos su estructura poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: @masterguru supongo que te refieres a esto:  [{id: 1, img: "..."}, {id: 2, img: "..."},{id: 3, img: "..."} ...]

Comment: No conozco react, pero creo que puedes hacer un console.log(product) o bien un console.log(item) para ver su estructura en la consola y pegarlo en la pregunta para que lo veamos.  Lo que has puesto no tiene la propiedad productImage.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kHGBGNf mira te adjunte la imagen de lo que viene en consola

Comment: Vale, entonces el `_id` siempre cambia... ¿porque quieres ponerlo en ese atributo `key` de toda la fila si cada `_id` solo se corresponde con 1 productImage y no 3?.  En todo caso ese key iria en la columna, y no en la fila, y entonces se arregla facil sacando el row del map y dejando el map con una sola columna

Comment: tu arreglo objeto product trae una cantidad de items, digamos 15 por ej, y lo que quieres es que en cada iteracion del carousel muestre de a 3?

Comment: @HernánGarcia Exacto eso quiero, ¿cómo podría?

Comment: @MairaAlejandraQuintero En [este enlace](https://dev.to/rakumairu/how-to-show-multiple-item-in-simple-react-carousel-32dd) lo explican, pero aparte de eso, para evitar repetir las imagenes, mírate mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Vista la estructura de tu objeto, donde cada propiedad **_id** se corresponde con una sola imagen de la propiedad **productImage**, me parece que esto es lo que buscas:

```
 <div style={{ paddingLeft: "5%", marginTop: "5%", paddingRight: "10%" }}>
      <div id="women">
        <Carousel autoplay>
          <div>
            <Row justify="space-around">
              {product.map((item) => (
                <Col span={7} key={item._id}>
                  <img src={item.productImage} alt="womenswear" height={300} />
                </Col>
              ))}
            </Row>
          </div>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
```